# What is a cost for Sitecore IPGeolocation Service?

Tags: geo-location

We would like to enable the geolocation service for our license. While on checking with the official documentation it looks like it is free of cost. But will it cost for using the service after some time period? Want to confirm the information regarding of the cost of service.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation that you can find [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html):

> The Sitecore IP Geolocation service is free of charge and with
> unlimited lookups per month.

**edit**
Just to clarify there is no timelimit to this, so this is not a trial period where you have to pay after a certain amount of time.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply